# jwplayer angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jwplayer

I am trying to create an angular directive that will update the url provided to a jwplayer when the element playlist-url is changed. I know/checked that when the scope(scope.tvUrl) changes in my controller that the el attribure playlist-url changes, so I know the problem is not in this part of the code.

```
<div pip-player playlist-url='{{tvUrl}}' channel-logo='{{channelLogo}}' id="pip-player"></div>
```

It is in my directive, the first console.log('ppTv hit') logs out but nothing runs in the link function, I thought that I am instantiating link in the 'return directive' part but I do not think that is the case. any help with the link part would be great or any suggestion with a different approach(using jwplayer as service instead) would be great. Thanks for the help!

```
(function(){
   'use strict';
     angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('pipPlayer', ppTv);

    function ppTv() {
        console.log('ppYv hit')
        var directive = {
             link: link,
             restrict: 'E',
             transclude: false,
             scope: {
                 playlistUrl: '@playlistUrl',
                 channelLogo: '@channelLogo',
             }
        }

        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('jwplayer is starting')

            jwplayer('pip-player').setup({
                width: '100%',
                height: 360,
                file: scope.playlistUrl,
                image: scope.channelLogo,
                //file: "http://yipcontent-lh.akamaihd.net/i/cincomas_1@395143/master.m3u8?hdnts=exp…%7Ehmac%3D82c581395560a25c69b4beb3f679bb65645c644d4a2f1ac1682e89821325aa74",
                //image: scope.channelLogo,
                primary: 'flash',
                autostart: true,
                fallback: true,
                androidhls: true,
                type: 'hls'
            });

        scope.$watch(attrs.pipPlayer, function(value) {
            format = value;
            updateChannel();
        });

    }
}

})();
```

Comment: You're calling `return directive;` before `scope.$watch` can run. Not sure that's the only problem, but fixing that's a start.

Comment: This helped solve my problem a little as well, thank you funrob

Answer (score 0):

So after some refactoring an understanding link better I found a solution.

jwDirective.js

```
(function() {
angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('pipScreen', ppTv);

function ppTv() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            playlistUrl: '@playurl'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            attributes.$observe('playurl', function(value) {
                jwplayer('pip-screen').setup({
                    file: value,
                    image: '@channelLogo',
                    primary: 'flash',
                    autostart: true,
                    fallback: true,
                    androidhls: true,
                    type: 'hls'
                });

            })

        }
    };
}
})()
```